# How can i use foxTooltip with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, tooltip

I want to import the library **foxToolTip** with angular.

I tried `import * as foxToolTip from 'fox.tooltip.js';`

but the `[ts]` doesn't found the module `fox.tooltip.js`

I installed the version : `fox.tooltip.js: 1.0.13,`

Comment: This is a very outdated library with invalid "main" entry in package.json file. I would NOT recommend you use it. There are various good replacement out there.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Angular 5, inside `.angular-cli.json`'s `scripts` array, add the path to fox.tooltip.js

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/fox.tooltip.js/dist/foxToolTip.min.js"
],
```

In case of Angular 6, inside `angular.json`'s `scripts` array, add the path to fox.tooltip.js without `../`

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/fox.tooltip.js/dist/foxToolTip.min.js"
],
```

and then, inside your Component, just declare a variable named foxToolTip like this:

```
declare var foxToolTip: any;
```

You **don't** need to do

```
import * as foxToolTip from 'fox.tooltip.js'
```

as your the compiler will throw an error stating that:

> Cannot find module 'fox.tooltip.js'.

Just adding the script to the scripts array in .angular-cli will add it to the global scope and you'll be able to access it from your components.

Also, make sure that you call any function on it inside the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook method as it tries to access the DOM elements by id.