# Angular | Import JavaScript library into component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to use the package `YoastSEO` inside of my Angular project so I can replicate what it does in WordPress.

The package via NPM is actually a JavaScript library.

Reading online it tells me that I should do `import * as YoastSEO from 'yoastseo'` which I have done.

However, when compiling the angular app with `ng serve` I get the error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/yoastseo/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/WritableStream.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'admin-panel\node_modules\yoastseo\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib'

I have never come across this issue before and I have tried to do `npm i htmlparser2` as a bit of a long shot to see if that would fix it put it doesn't seem too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated whether this being a new npm package to use or how to fix this issue.

Comment: are you sure this package is for client-side and not server-side ?

Comment: In the examples they use `window.onload` I thought that was a client side?

Comment: yes it is, sorry

Comment: can you add link to this package?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry the link is https://www.npmjs.com/package/yoastseo

Comment: try this `npm i htmlparser2@^3.9.2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897552/2622292

Comment: Although the module is different but the procedure is the same.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I followed that method but that doesn't seem to work. The app now compiles but using `App` it's saying its not defined

Comment: Infact the issue I am getting now is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Fun fact - This node_module doesn't even have a `yeastseo.min.js` or something.

Comment: I did see that @SiddharthAjmera does that mean that there's no way to do this? Or would I have to minify the js myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179281/discussion-between-tallent123-and-siddharth-ajmera).

Comment: There's definitely a way. I just don't happen to know about it. Let's wait for someone to ansewr this.