# what is the right way to import a node module to angular typescript / angularcli

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, pako

im importing some "legacy"  (non typescript) js libs to my angular SPA.

normally I just add a load from the cdn to index.html like:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pako/1.0.6/pako.min.js"></script>
```

and in the angular-component i just decale

```
declare var pako: any;
```

this typically works.   Now i like to "host" this lib locally. I can add it to the angular project with

```
npm install pako
```

But how do I add it than to the angular app ?
I tested adding an import to polyfills.ts  (this works for hammerjs but not for pako)

Also this should work for ng build  (and than probably get added to the compiled / packed runtime.js

BTW: here is a test stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-load-pako

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897552/2622292

Comment: You’ve added it via an external script reference. Others that install pako will also have to do the same - via a script tag.

Comment: actually to import below works fine and sound elegant to me for the npm package. I do not need to know the path to the lib pako.min.js just the npm package name. 
Have not tried the script tga in angular.json - is there any advantage ?   
(for both it seems to got packed into vendor.js)

Comment: type definitions for pako: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pako/index.d.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I love all the questions that provide a stackblitz link so that I can easily provide the correct answer:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-load-pako-gfunsb

Basically, you just need to do:

`import * as pako from 'pako';`

Comment: Thnks was so easy