# CamanJs with angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, types, camanjs

I am trying to use camanjs with angular 6. How to add js lib and use it with angular when there are no types for it on npm. I follow many steps

- install  caman using npm
- adding it to angular.json as a script using its path in node modules
- import it into the component like

> import * as Caman from 'path to caman in node module'

- the in AfterViewInit I use it like

> ```
>   ngAfterViewInit() {
>        Caman('#image-id', function () {
>             this.brightness(10);
>             this.contrast(20);
>           });
>      }
> ```

but when start server I get this error

[image]

link to code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5g941

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895876/how-can-i-use-foxtooltip-with-angular/51897552#51897552

Comment: I followed these steps and give me an error in console "caman is not defined"

Comment: Please consider creating a stackblitz so that someone could investigate.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5g941

Comment: thanks @SiddharthAjmera  it works your answer was very useful.

Comment: Is the bounty still open?

Comment: yes but I don't know how to assign it to comment

Comment: Let me post an answer in that case.

Comment: It would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First do as [How can i use foxTooltip with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895876/how-can-i-use-foxtooltip-with-angular/51897552#51897552)
- Then add Caman.pack.js from nodemodules _ under caman folder into assets
- Make sure your declared var in the beginning of the Component is the Same name as in Package  "Caman" case senstive

Answer (score 1):

Inside `.angular-cli.json`'s `scripts` array, add the path to `caman`

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/path-to-caman"
],
```

In case of Angular 6 in `angular.json`'s `scripts` array, add the path to `caman`

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/path-to-caman"
],
```

and then, inside your Component, just declare a variable named `Caman` like this:

```
declare var Caman: any;
```

You **don't** need to do

```
import * as Caman from 'path-to-caman'
```

as your compiler will throw an error stating that:

> Cannot find module 'caman'.

Just adding the script to the scripts array in `.angular-cli`/`angular.json`(in case of Angular 6) will add it to the global scope and you'll be able to access it from your components.

Also, make sure that you call any function on it inside the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook method as it tries to access the DOM elements by id.