# I want to Import javaScript libraries like camanjs, lena.js, jimp in angular app. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, angular, image-processing

I want to process my image in the frontend angular app. I need to extract the text using tesseract.js. I did it. But in some cases, the image needs to be processed. And I can't find any source that helps image processing using angular. Javascript libraries are available but not being able to import those libraries. What should I do to import camanjs, lena.js, and jimp in my angular application?

Answer (score 0):

All of these libraries are to be installed as a npm packages.
You can just go ahead and install them via npm itself like: `npm install tesseract.js@2.1.1` and after that import them in your component `import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';`  which makes Tesseract (Or any other package you've installed) available throughout your component. Go ahead and check out [Tesseracts npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js/v/2.1.1) for further instructions.

Comment: I did work with tesseract.js. But I can not import camanjs, lena.js or jimp the way I imported tesseract.

Comment: [You can find out more for non npm packages in that answer on post #52206640](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52253528/8594609)