# How to import a js file in Angular Library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10

I am creating a Angular Library which will be using a js file for operations. How do I import this file in Library since it doesn't contain angular.json file.

In Normal app which could just add it to scripts in angular json and access through global variable but not sure about this.

Comment: It depends on what 3rd lib you want to use. Can you give a name ?

Comment: like opencv.js @HungCung

Comment: [You can check Sidd Ajmeras answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206640/camanjs-with-angular-6/52253528#52253528)

Comment: @SarfrazAnwar it looks like you are not using angular-cli for generating library right ?

Comment: Not sure about that. What difference does it make ? @HungCung