# How to import a simple JS into an angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, aspnetboilerplate

I am developing an application based on the angular version of aspnetboilerplate (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) which uses the BSBAdmin template (https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/) the template has a material themed switch that I want to use (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/).
I installed the bootstrap-select using `npm i bootstrap-select` and the code shows on node_modules, in my component I was able to include the css listing the css file on `styleUrls` on the ts file, but I can't figure how to include the js.

I tried including in the html file but angular removes it, I tried importing in the ts file but it is not a module or component, I can't find an equivalent to `styleUrls` for scripts.

I am pretty new to angular, so I may be doing things in a completely wrong way, thanks for any help.

Comment: You can either add it into the `scripts` array of `angular.json`, or add it as a `script` tag in the `index.html` file

Comment: Is there any StackBlitz sample for reference? I've answered questions like these before that you might want to have a look at here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897552/2622292

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52253528/2622292

Comment: So I can't add it just to the component like with css? I have to add it to all pages?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, that would be an anti-pattern. You should be using the styles instead of the actual html. You can style your html select list with that. Or probably if this lib exposes an Angular component, you could use that in your template via its selector.

Comment: To clarify, I am using css files linked but I am linking the files in the @Component, so they only get included when needed, I am trying to do the same with js files. I followed the link and managed to import the file but it does not seem to affect the browser. 
this is what my file looks like:
`import * as bootstrapSelect from 'bootstrap-select'`
`declare var bootstrapSelect: any;`

@Component({
    selector: 'cp-modal',
    templateUrl: './cp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cp.component.css',
     '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css']
})
``

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript file path in index.html.

```
<script src="assets/js/abc.js"></script>
```

abc is javascript file name.
and another solution is add the JS file in the angular.json like this way,

```
"scripts":[
"src/assets/js/sbc.js"
]
```